# process files uploaded by django-ajax-uploader

Tags: django

I have successfully implemented django-ajax-uploader into my project. But I do not know how to call a django function to process the uploaded file automatically once the file was uploaded to site. There is no any sample code on its site. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own backend that implements any custom behaviour by overriding the provided methods. Here is the base model for a backend:

https://github.com/GoodCloud/django-ajax-uploader/blob/master/ajaxuploader/backends/base.py#L19

so simply create your own that inherits from this and overwrite `upload_complete`, and as mentioned in the docs:

> To use another backend, specify it when instantiating AjaxFileUploader

Comment: Thank you pastylegs. I was digging for a while.